# chain text from ListView.builder in flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

is there a way of chaining (joining?) text together from ListView.builder so it is just one long text? I've tried getting this done with GridView instead but the aspect ratio messes the whole thing up. I'm using TextScroll (https://pub.dev/packages/text_scroll), which works great but I just can't figure out how to connect the text together. the option to join() isn't there?

What I'm after:[image: This is just by using text but I need it to be from Firebase]

And what I'm getting :( [image: as expected it's a list]

My code:

```
    class TopNewsBar extends StatelessWidget {
  const TopNewsBar({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var constraints = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: constraints * .03),
      child: Container(
        decoration:
            BoxDecoration(color: grey, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(14)),
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 14.0, horizontal: 25),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child: Text(
                  'Trending Now: ',
                  style: h3b.copyWith(color: red),
                ),
              ),
              Flexible(
                flex: 11,
                child: StreamBuilder(
                  stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                      .collection("Posts")
                      .orderBy("timestamp", descending: true)
                      .snapshots(),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      return ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: 5,
                          physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            final post = snapshot.data!.docs[index];
                            final scrollingtext = post["title"] + "    •    ";
                            final fulltext = scrollingtext;
                            return TextScroll(fulltext);
                          });
                    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                      return Center(
                        child: Text('Error${snapshot.error}'),
                      );
                    } else {
                      return const Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      );
                    }
                  },
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply join the texts together and display it using one `TextScroll`
instead of using a `ListView`.

```dart
builder: (context, snapshot) {
  if (snapshot.hasData) {
    final posts = snapshot.data!.docs;
    final joinedPostTitle = posts.map((post) => post['title'] as String).join('    •    ');
    return TextScroll(joinedPostTitle);
  } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
    return Center(
      child: Text('Error${snapshot.error}'),
    );
  } else {
    return const Center(
      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Don't know why I didn't think about that feel like a dummy.